# Error in Multiple Input Path in MapReduce

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I am writing a Multiple Input Mapreduce program in Eclipse, below are the part of code lines

Code:

```
Path map1=new Path(args[0]);
Path map2=new Path(args[1]);

MultipleInputs.**addInputPath**(job,map1, TextInputFormat.class,Mapper1.class);
MultipleInputs.**addInputPath**(job,map2, TextInputFormat.class,Mapper2.class);
```

In the "addInputpath" i am getting error as below,

Error : The method addInputPath(Job, Path, Class, Class) in the type MultipleInputs is not applicable for the arguments (Job, Path, Class, Class)

Can anyone help on these?

Please find the code in the below link

https://www.dropbox.com/s/fm3m0ed4gh6jy98/Code

Regards,
vishwa

Comment: Are you sure you are properly following the syntax mapper class? i.e org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper<KEYIN,VALUEIN,KEYOUT,VALUEOUT>.

Comment: @Vishwa, are you able to solve you problem? If not please check my new edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

What I can tell is you have wrongly imported an incompatible,

```
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat;
```

which should have been,

```
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.TextInputFormat;
```

Hadoop offers two APIs to create a job, one belongs to  org.apache.hadoop.mapred and other is org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce. I think you are using the latter and that's the one you should import.

Comment: I have added the correct classes,I am providing the code in my question with link

Comment: @Vishwa, I figured out your problem, please see the edited answer. Thanks.

Comment: import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.lib.input.TextInputFormat; not able to add this class its showing as The import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.lib.input cannot be resolved

Comment: @Vishwa: it's not org.apache.hadoop.mapred.lib.input.TextInputFormat but import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.TextInputFormat;

Comment: @Vishwa: You can accept answers if it worked. That motivates us to answer more. Thanks!